# Can I get a HVAC diagram that shows vent locations and components for 2005 Ford Freestar

Tags: hvac, heater, diagram

I have a 2005 Ford Freestar that has floor and ceiling vents in the back of the cab. I'm interested in installing a 3rd party external heater and would like to see the ventilation routings to determine if I can connect to existing ventilation system instead of punching holes through the cabin or similar. I found some views for the HVAC equipment E.G. heater core, etc. but ideally would have ventilation views or route mappings.

Can I get diagrams or exploded views of the vent routing and layout? If so where can I find them?

Comment: A workshop manual is a good investment.

Answer (score 0):

For that vehicle, and that model year, I would think this is a perfect junk yard pick-a-part project. Save money, learn how it all goes together, etc.. The camera on your mobile phone is your buddy. Take plenty of pictures when you are taking things apart at the junk yard. Re-assemble when you get home.

Note: I've grabbed these two links, not because you need that exact part, but for the reference diagram attached there. You can get hints from those diagrams to assist you with appropriate search terms.

Hoses:
https://parts.ford.com/shop/en/us/engine/other-engine-parts/clip-heater-hose-6268429-1

Auxiliary HVAC Unit:
https://parts.ford.com/shop/en/us/climate-control/heater-repair-parts/core-assy-heater-6308691-1

I've been searching this site for diagrams of the auxiliary (rear) system air handling, and I'm not finding much.  I thought the overhead duct work for that vehicle was integral to the headliner. There may be simple stove pipe style tubing to connect the ends.